# Smallest job first algorithm implementation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge

I have implemented smallest job first algorithm using javascript. It was part of a coding challenge. I would like to ask for evaluation of my script. I would like to get suggestions to improve my code performance. Which parts of the code I can improve. Is there an alternative to for loops?

Function takes jobs array with transaction time and index. Returns the clock cycles of the process/job at specific index. Function Call with sample input, `sjf([10, 3, 15, 8, 7], 3)`.

Here is the code.

```
function sjf(jobs, index) {

// declare waiting time array
var waitingTime = [];
// set waiting time for first task to zero
waitingTime[0] = 0;

// declare total time array
var totalTimeArray = [];

var processArray = [];
// add job value and index as an object to process array
for (i=0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
    processArray.push({
        id: i,
        value: jobs[i]
    })
}

// sort the array in ascending order
function sortArray(a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
}

// calculate waiting time for each process except first process
// waiting time for first process is zero so we start to calculate from index 1
function calculateWaitingTime(sortedArray, waitingTime) {
    for (i=1; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
        waitingTime.push(sortedArray[i-1].value + waitingTime[i-1]);
    }
}

// total time taken to complete each task
function calculateTimeForEachTask(sortedArray, totalTimeArray) {
    for (i=0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
        totalTimeArray.push({
            id: sortedArray[i].id,
            time: sortedArray[i].value + waitingTime[i]
        });
    }
}

// find clock cycles
function findClockCycles(totalTimeArray, index) {
    for (i = 0; i < totalTimeArray.length; i++) {
        if (totalTimeArray[i].id === index) {
            return totalTimeArray[i].time;
        }
    }
}

// First of all sort the process array in ascending order of their value
var sortedArray = processArray.sort(sortArray);

// calculate waiting time for the rest of the processes
calculateWaitingTime(sortedArray, waitingTime);


// calculate total time for each task
calculateTimeForEachTask(sortedArray, totalTimeArray);

// return clock cycles for the task
return findClockCycles(totalTimeArray, index);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can be done with far less code. Like this:

```
function calculateTotalClockCycles(jobs, index) {
  jobs.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return jobs.slice(0, index).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

alert(calculateTotalClockCycles([10, 3, 15, 8, 7], 3));
```

In the first line of code inside the function, the jobs are sorted, small to large. The second line is more complicated. The `reduce()` method is used to sum all the values of the array it applies to. That array is the wanted part (slice) of the whole sorted jobs array.

So here `reduce()` is used as an alternative for a 'for' loop.

Comment: This is merely 3 lines of code. I had no idea, that it could be solved like this. I am wondering why nothing came into my mind for such a solution. @KIKO do this school of thought belongs to functional programming? And what steps could I take to polish my skills and thought process to create solutions like you have provided.

Comment: In my opinion it all comes down to paying attention to what others do, reading 'books', and a lot of practice. You have to be able to think logically and to reduce a problem to its essence. I've been doing this for 36 years, you can't beat that. However, I actually had to look up the Javascript methods I used, so I guess that part of it is not being afraid of reading documentation. I used this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array It's all there. That said: I don't exclude the possibility that there are better/nicer solutions possible.

Comment: Any reason you used an arrow function for `reduce`, but the longer `function` syntax for `sort`?

Comment: @Gerrit0 No, didn't spent any thought on that. Those were the examples I found in the documentation, and used. You could indeed write `(a, b) => a - b` in the sort method. That looks nice. I'll replace the `function(a, b) { return a - b; }` with it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I just realized that this answer might be wrong. The current solution sorts the array and after sorting the index of lets say number 8 changes to 2 where as in original array it is 3. As far as I understood, I needed to calculate the time of the task against original index and not the index of the sorted array.

Comment: In that case your original code might also be wrong? Your description of the algorithm is minimal, so I looked at what your code does. As far as I know, the results of your code, and mine, are the same. If you want the code to do something else, you can ask a new question, for instance in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com). Try to be precise in the description of the needed algorithm, give examples, and wanted results.